# Constructing Rectangular with Python

Tags: python, class, methods, rectangles

Is there any way to make area() refer to check()?
Currently, codes of check() is the same in area().

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2

    def check(self): #Checking this rectangle 
        if abs(self.x1-self.x2) == 0 or abs(self.y1-self.y2)==0:
            return False
        else :
            return True

    def area(self): #Calculating width
        if abs(self.x1-self.x2) == 0 or abs(self.y1-self.y2)==0:
            return False
        else : 
            area = abs(self.x1-self.x2)*abs(self.y1-self.y2)
            return area
```

Comment: `if not self.check():`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `check(self)` method, you don't need any if nor `abs()`.
You can just do:

```
def check(self):
    return self.x1 != self.x2 and self.y1 != self.y2
```

About the `area(self)` method, you could just do:

```
def area(self):
    if not self.check():
        return False
    else:
        return abs(self.x1-self.x2)*abs(self.y1-self.y2)
```

Now your code should be cleaner.